# WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400 in kubernetes-ingress

Tags: websocket, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Facing this issue if I am connecting to ingress for web socket service
failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

**Ingress YAML**

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: websocket-producer-cdph
spec:
  rules:
    host: some.domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          path: "/"
          backend:
            serviceName: websocket-producer-cdph
            servicePort: 8183
status:
loadBalancer:
ingress:
{}
```

**Service YAML**

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: websocket-producer-cdph
spec:
  ports:    
    name: ws
    protocol: TCP
    port: 8183
    targetPort: 8183
selector:
  app: websocket-producer-cdph
clusterIP: 10.100.254.99
type: ClusterIP
sessionAffinity: None
status:
loadBalancer:
{}
```

When I try to listen ws://some.domain.com/ws it's showing
Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

*/ws is the path*

But if go and update spec type in service to LoadBalancer, it'll generate an IP 192.168.1.17:8183 and listening to that ws://192.168.1.17:8183/ws its working but I need to expose the URL using ingress so it can be used outside of the network.

I am using the following image for ingress controller:

**quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.19.0**

How can I create ingress for a web-socket service?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 6):

As stated in the [nginx-ingress documentation](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/websocket#websocket-support), to proxy WebSocket traffic you should use annotation with the name of websocket service. Don't forget to use quotes:

```
nginx.org/websocket-services: "service1[,service2,...]"
```

In this example from the [documentation](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/websocket#websocket-support), WebSocket is enabled only for one of three services (`ws-svc`):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: cafe-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.org/websocket-services: "ws-svc"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: cafe.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /tea
        backend:
          serviceName: tea-svc
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /coffee
        backend:
          serviceName: coffee-svc
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /ws
        backend:
          serviceName: ws-svc
          servicePort: 8008
```

Comment: This repo provides an implementation of an Ingress controller for NGINX and NGINX Plus. This implementation is different from the NGINX Ingress controller in kubernetes/ingress-nginx repo. See this doc to find out about the key differences.

[https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/docs/nginx-ingress-controllers.md]

**I am using kubernetes/ingress-nginx repo**

[https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx]

In [https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress] , readme.md they CLEARLY stated, **BOTH CONTROLLER ARE DIFFERENT.**

Comment: Thank you for information. Your links were very helpful. Could you check your ingress-controller /etc/nginx.conf content for the presence of the following lines in the service location? <proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;> and < proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;> I believe they should be present to enable WebSocket functionality for the backend.

Comment: `# Pass the extracted client certificate to the backend`    

                        `# Allow websocket connections`     
                        `proxy_set_header                        Upgrade           $http_upgrade;`     

                        `proxy_set_header                        Connection       `   `$connection_upgrade;`     

                        `proxy_set_header X-Request-ID           $req_id;`    
                        `proxy_set_header X-Real-IP              $the_real_ip;`    

I checked its there

Comment: Can't say more without seeing the whole nginx.conf from your ingress-controller. Could you upload it on github and provide a link?

Answer (score 1):

try add annotation`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-hash-by: "$arg_token"`

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/2097

Answer (score -1):

You want to add the `nginx.org/websocket-services` annotation to your ingress resource definition. That, in turn, tells nginx to support websockets (which I believe has to do with the Upgrade/Connection headers?).

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: websocket-producer-cdph
  annotations:
    nginx.org/websocket-services: "websocket-producer-cdph"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: some.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: websocket-producer-cdph
          servicePort: 8183
```

Comment: ` 
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: websocket-producer-3tlb
  namespace: dpqa
  annotations:
    nginx.org/websocket-services: websocket-producer-3tlb
spec:
  rules:
  - host: some.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: "/"
        backend:
          serviceName: websocket-producer-3tlb
          servicePort: 8183
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - {}
`

Tried this still not able to listen, same handshake exception is coming

And this annotation is for nginx-ingress and i am using kubernetes-ingress